# Is there a naming convention for n*3 registers which are semantically connected?

Tags: c, assembly, embedded, naming-conventions, microcontroller

I know the naming convention which says if there are n*2 registers or variables which are semantically connected you should name them like following:

```
REGH REGL
```

In the case of 2*2 registers it would be:

```
REGHH REGHL REGLH REGLL
```

The last two letters stand for high-high, high-low, low-high and low-low. Is there any convention which declares the same thing for 3 registers? Like:

```
REGH REGM REGL
```

In this case the last letters stand for high, middle and low. 6 byte would look like this:

```
REGHH REGHM REGHL REGLH REGLM REGLL
```

I hope you understand what I mean. Is there any convention for this case?

Comment: The one you just made up looks perfectly sane to me ...

Comment: I don't know. If you name them like this and you see a register `REGH` in a source code it could imply that there is only another `REGL`. There is no hint for an existing `REGM`.

Comment: Would all these registers be abtracted to a `struct`?

Comment: What is the context of this question?  Are you designing a 24/48 bit  processor? H/M/L is OK. The second one is stretching it, I would already avoid HH/HL/LH/LL and rather use numbers.

Comment: I'm in VHDL context. I'm using the Oregano 8051 IP Core (http://www.oreganosystems.at/?page_id=96). I've added my own SFR for a prescaler. The question is how should I name the register parts in C code when I want to declare it. At the moment I have named them: `__sfr __at (0xC0) PRSCLL; __sfr __at (0xC1) PRSCLM; __sfr __at (0xC2) PRSCLH;` @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey I have no intention to group them into a `struct`.

Comment: What you invented sounds reasonable, but you might consider changing the order in memory to HML. @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey brings up a common idea. You can do what you are doing but also declare a struct that starts at 0xC0. Then you could also reference the registers as PRSCL.HIGH, PRSCL.MED, and PRSCL.LOW. This is a pretty common practice.

Comment: About the HML order: take a look at the SFR memory map of Intel 8051 (http://www.zimagez.com/full/c57a683d2c0ffeaa329a618ec91320d494ecf6c66d12b2e0a00c76c086fa6e45ae74fa4a98c36a083d912ca9adcf7c84082522dd34113be34bda7d8528202f3b.php). For example the DP registers at 0x82 and 0x83. They were ordered by LH. Is there a special reason why you suggest HML order? About structs: let's say I don't want to use structs or I'm using assembly at all :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Atmel AVR Microcontroller, 1st ed. [P. 173; 6.10.1]](http://books.google.at/books?id=TSYLAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA173&lpg=PA173)

> For a register larger than 16 bits, the bytes are numbered from the least significant byte. For example, the 32-bit ADC calibration register is named CAL. The four bytes are named CAL0, CAL1, CAL2, CAL3 (from the least to the most significant byte).

So in a 8-bit system we shouldn't even do:

```
REGHH REGHL REGLH REGLL
```

but:

```
REG3 REG2 REG1 REG0
```